# Why is a factor being returned when I subset a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, factors

I'm still a bit of a newb to R programming.  I'm confused why subsetting a data frame returns a factor as opposed to just a vector with a single element.  Why is this R's default?  Is this because what I'm subsetting is a word, and not a value?  Still, I'd expect a character vector then.

For example:

```
n <- c(2,3,5)
s = c("aa", "bb","cc")
b <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
df <- data.frame(n,s,b)
df

test <- df[1,"s"]
test
class(test)  #this says it's a factor
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I think I found the answer I was looking for, which is really *why* subsets of characters in R data frames are stored as factors, as opposed to being stored as single elements of a vector. Meaning, the *purpose* behind it, not just the fact that it does- which can easily just be seen in `?data.frame()`.

After doing some research, it turns out that the purpose of this is actually to create a safeguard from applying nominal (categorical, non-ordinal) data the wrong way in statistical analysis (for example, it doesn't make sense to have *more* of a nominal value- changing colors is not *more* of something, just nominally different.

This site really helped clear it up for me: http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/factors.html

Thanks for the responses!

Answer (score 4):

The `data.frame()` function by default turns character vectors into factors. If you do not want this behavior, use `data.frame(..., stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`.

Also note that R doesn't have "single values," it just has vectors. Even the number `1` is just a length-one numeric vector.

Comment: yes, that's why I wrote, "... as opposed to just a vector with a single element"

Answer (score 3):

See `?data.frame`. One default setting of `data.frame()` is to convert character vectors, such as your `s = c("aa", "bb","cc")` to factors. To change this, you need to modify the argument `stringsAsFactors` from it's default of `TRUE` to `FALSE`.

Here's how you can modify your code:

```
n <- c(2,3,5)
s = c("aa", "bb","cc")
b <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
df <- data.frame(n,s,b, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df

test <- df[1,"s"]
test
class(test)  #Now returns character.
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact `test` is not a vector even though has a single element. It has attributes `levels`, and the `class` one which identifies it as a factor. `?vector` specifies that:

> factors are not vectors

The confusion may arise between `is.atomic` and `is.vector` where the latter returns `TRUE` to objects that has no attributes other than the name.

```
 attributes(test)
$levels
[1] "aa" "bb" "cc"

$class
[1] "factor"

 is.atomic(test)
[1] TRUE
 length(test)
[1] 1
is.vector(test)
[1] FALSE
```

the question might be returned back, because if you see:

```
 sapply(df, class)
        n         s         b 
"numeric"  "factor" "logical"
```

why R should convert the class of the object you subset? with `test <- df[1,"s"]` you subsetted a factor and that is what R gives back to you. Maybe sometimes it could be better to change this behavior... maybe, but imagine that if the case it would be necessary to create rules for subsetting that change the `class` attributes. An hard task I think.